Is it a roman chair? What is its use?
The following equipment is being sold online as Roman Chair. Is it? I believe Roman Chair can be used for hyperextension, but the equipment shown in the images cannot be. What else can it be used for?




Reverse image search gives me a "Protoner weight training chair for home gym" that is an exact match of the images you provide. It seems to be an Indian fitness brand.
The description on the website says:

Protoner chair for home gym station
Used with dumbbells for numerous exercises
specially designed for flat back and strong hold during exercises
weight capacity 200 kgs including user weight

So it's clearly not a roman chair, just some sort of bench for seated exercises (curls, lateral raises, shoulder presses, etc). You'd use the foot hold to keep your body stable while you move your arms.
This is what a standard roman chair usually looks like (there are other variations):


Ok. I found it here https://www.tatacliq.com/protoner-weight-training-roman-chair-black-size---1041x457/p-mp000000018535069.
Which says its a roman chair.

@6nagi9 You asked if it was a roman chair. Search for 'roman chair workout', you'll quickly notice you can't use this chair for any of that, and the equipment used doesn't resemble the one in your question at all. So it looks like the website where you found it is wrong.

@6nagi9 you also asked what can it be used for, which I also answered. You won't be able to do hyperextensions with your chair, only seating exercises with a fixed foot position.
